# Vue props type with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

When a prop type is Number, String or Boolean, it will given the corrent type promty:

[image]

but when prop type is Object, it will be an any type:

[image]

and when i cast the Object to a function that returns the interface you’d like, it will be given the corrent type also:

[image]

I find the prop type declaration in options.d.ts

```
export type Prop<T> = { (): T } | { new (...args: any[]) => T & object }
```

But i do not know what mean is it, and how does it infer the type?

Comment: You have a typo in `required`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is so-called *constructor type*.

More strictly, this property can appear in following different ways:

- as a generic function `(): T` returning the specified type `T`;
- as a generic constructor `new (...args): T & object`, creating the object of specified type `T` with additional properties from type `object`.

The `Object` type satisfies the second variant, i.e. it's a class with some constructor property. It has the following definition (from `lib.es5.d.ts`):

```
interface Object {
  /** The initial value of Object.prototype.constructor is the standard built-in Object constructor. */
  constructor: Function;
  // some more properties here
}
```

Note that this is the most general constructor possible, and so it could potentionally return *any* possible value. So the transpiler tells you exactly that - "you have a class whose constructor returns `any`".

Seems that you could just use `User` as property type. Since it's a class too, I suppose, it will have the signature of `new (...args) => User`, so it would infer exactly the type you need.

---

upd: missed the interface definition in the question. Well, if there's no reason to make it a class instead, the proper typing (and usage) seems to be the function: `() => User`, not `Object`.

Comment: Thinks a lot, but i still have the question: how does it infer the type i need?

And an other question, when i cast the Object to a interface, 
`Object as User`
it will be error. ***Type 'ObjectConstructor' cannot be converted to type 'User'. Property 'id' is missing in type 'ObjectConstructor'.***

it makes me wonder. why?

Thinks again.

Comment: You don't have to cast `Object as User`. If it's possible to make a `class User` instead of `interface User` (i.e. if it won't have a significant overhead - and I assume it won't), you can just write `propA: {type: User}`, without using `Object` at all. I think I'll update my answer a bit later, to give possibly a more verbose clarification.

Comment: Maybe i understand for the first, if the prop type is function, accronding to the  `type Prop<T> = { (): T } | { new (...args: any[]) => T & object }`,  it will create object that the properties is function return value. In the question, the properties is User,  Yes?

Comment: Right. You have the object of type `() => User`, as you've said explicitly by the `as` keyword. It fits into the first template: `{ () => T }` (since function is just an object with call signature); with `T = User`. So, `Prop<T>` infers to `Prop<User>`.

Comment: There are some question about it, please look at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51296287/about-the-reverse-inference-in-typescript

Comment: I see. It seems to be the issue with essentially the same type as here, right?

Comment: yes, It is the same question. It is different than I thought.