# About the reverse inference in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

this is my test code:

```
type Prop<T> = { new(...args: any[]): T } | { (): T }
declare function propTest<T>(t: Prop<T>): T
```

when i define a class, it will be ok:

```
class User {}
propTest(User) // User
```

But when i pass it with native constructors:

```
propTest(String) // String(not string)
```

The reason is `String` satisfy both call and constructor signature.

So my question is what should i do to get the compiler to infer the native type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I take it you'd like `T` to be inferred from the callable signature (`()=>T`) before it gets inferred from the newable signature (`new(...args: any[])=>T`), but the compiler doesn't want to do that for you?  I guess the newable signature always takes priority (it doesn't matter if you switch the order of the union constituents).

Luckily, there's a trick to lowering the priority of an inference site, mentioned by @RyanCavanaugh (one of the language maintainers) in a [GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731):

> `T & { }` creates a "lower-priority" inference site for `T` *by design*. I would move this from the "definitely don't depend on this" column to the "it's probably going to work for the foreseeable future" column.

So the trick is to intersect something with the empty object type.  Let's see if it works:

```
type Prop<T> = { (): T } | { new(...args: any[]): (T & {}) }
```

I've put the `T & {}` in the newable signature, to try to lower its priority.  Here goes:

```
propTest(String) // string
```

And let's just make sure it still works for `User`:

```
propTest(User) // User
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Why don't just check the inversed order: `type Prop<T> = { (): T } | { new(...args: any[]): T }`? For me, it works just well: `String` satisfies the first signature and don't even check the second.

Comment: @Cerberus `String` satisfy both call and constructor signature. Note if  `String` satisfy the first signature, it will be inferred a `string`(not `String`), according to the StringConstructor interface in lib.es5.d.ts,

Comment: I find  `type Prop<T> = { (): T } | { new(...args: any[]): T & object }` work as well, I think the reason it worked is the same as you said.

Infact `type Prop<T> = { (): T } | { new(...args: any[]): T | number}` will be worked also.

Comment: I found the relevant code: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/types.ts#L4111, But, i can not understand it.